# Keep order in a key-value use case with additions and deletions

Tags: database, database-design, key-value

I receive big 4 bit hashes list from an API that I need to store.
The list must always be ordered alphanumerically.

Here's how things are flowing :

- I get the full list of hashes from the API (Approx 1,000,000). I store this list.
- I request the API periodically to get a list of additions and deletions to the list.

---

For now I store the hashes list with a 'order' row in a table :

- **0** - 6717
- **1** - 7fcd
- **2** - 88c6
- **3** - 9e63
- **4** - dcb0
- **5** - fb44

Now let's say I receive the deletions :

- **1**
- **4**

And the additions :

- 7bd7
- 0e33

---

I need to delete the rows **1** and **4** :

- **0** - 6717
- **2** - 88c6
- **3** - 9e63
- **5** - fb44

And I need to add the additions to the list *AND* to rebuild the roder row to keep the alphaneumeric order, to be able to to this again :

- **0** - 0e33
- **1** - 6717
- **2** - 7bd7
- **3** - 88c6
- **4** - 9e63
- **5** - fb44

---

I need this for a PHP Symfony application, I have implemented this with MySQL but it's pretty slow to create the full list and to rebuild the id row...

As I have a key->value dataset Redis seems to be a good choice but there is no bulk rename function for the keys.

I am also thinking about MongoDB and to create one document for each hash but I'm not really sure.

what would you do ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In relational data model (YesSQL world) a table is an **non-ordered** set of rows. Hence, the order of stored values is unpredictable "by design" in general case (I wouldn't say about clustered indexes here). The ordered list is **only guaranteed** when using `ORDER BY` clause

```
SELECT key, value FROM my_store WHERE ... ORDER BY key
```

For the performance purposes you need to have an index/primary key/unique constraint (depend on DMBS and database design) on the affected column(s). 1M of rows is a relatively small amount which shouldn't make some performance issues. Be aware also of data/index fragmentation when deletion and insertion are frequent.